# Html in textview android

Tags: android, html, textview

I am dealing with the following html

```
<div style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"> My Text </div>
```

When using the class html.fromHtml to display my html into a textview I lose the text properties. How can I display the html in a text view properly?

Comment: if all tags is not supported than spanned string is alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

not all the html/css tags are supported by `Html.fromHtml`. [Here](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) you can find an unofficial list of the supported tags

Comment: I know that not all tags are supported but as i use only supported tag it still shows me error